# Adding from one div to another with javascript with appendchild(not working)

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, appendchild

Hey there so i'm trying to make a "Website" where you can add and remove people from a list and add to another. Adding works but removing doesn't work properly. As you can see the add and remove clause is very similar to each another the only difference is the id in the `getElementById()`.

```js
let names = [];
names[0] = "Daniel";
names[1] = "Anna";
names[2] = "Sarah";
names[3] = "Karl";
names[4] = "Tim";
names[5] = "Simon";
names[6] = "Klara";
names[7] = "David";
names[8] = "Hugo";

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",add);

document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click",remove);

for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    document.getElementById("participants").innerHTML += "<div class='normal' id='"+names[i]+"'>"+names[i]+"</div>";
}

for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    document.getElementById(names[i]).addEventListener("click",chosen); 
}

function chosen(){
    let item = document.getElementById(this.id);
    if(item.classList.contains("chosen")){
        item.classList.remove("chosen");
    }else{
        item.classList.add("chosen");
    }
}

function add(){
    let arr = [];
    arr = document.getElementsByClassName("chosen");

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("members").appendChild(arr[i]);
    }
}

function remove(){
    let test = []; 
    test = document.getElementsByClassName("chosen");
    console.log(test);

    for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("participants").appendChild(test[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If each element would have an ID that is unique, then you could simply select by that ID with `document.querySelector('#uniqueID')` and just call `.remove()` on that element. You can set the ID of a DOM element with `element.setAttribute('id', 'value')`

And I don't recommend using `innerHTML`, consider creating the DOM elements with `document.createElement('div')`, then you can use `innerText` to set the text.

More advanced technique would be to use Array methods like `filter`, but I think you are not there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had several bugs in the code, chosen class didn't cleaned up after adding and removing items, not all of the elements were added or removed. 
the following resolve those issues. 
i advise that you'll refactor it and make it more generic, if you need help ping me.

```
const names = ["Daniel", "Anna", "Sarah", "Karl", "Tim" ,"Simon", "Klara", "David"];

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",add);

document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click",remove);



for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("participants").innerHTML += "<div class='normal' id='"+names[i]+"'>"+names[i]+"</div>";

}
for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){

    document.getElementById(names[i]).addEventListener("click",chosen); 
}

function chosen(){
    let item = document.getElementById(this.id);

        if(item.classList.contains("chosen")){
            item.classList.remove("chosen");

        }else{
            item.classList.add("chosen");

        }

}

function add(){
    members = document.getElementById("members");
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".chosen")).forEach((item)=> { 
        members.append(item)
        item.classList.remove("chosen");
    })  
}

function remove(){
    participants = document.getElementById("participants");
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".chosen")).forEach((item)=> { 
        participants.append(item)
        item.classList.remove("chosen");
    })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a better approach if you added the items first and, set a eventlistener, listening `click` on the parent element. Depending on the target, you would dispatch the `chosen` function.

You can take advantage of Event bubbling to do this. when you create separate `for` statements, it's not guaranteed the element will be in the DOM right after the for statement finishes to run.

```
var participants = document.getElementById('participants');

participants.onclick = function(event){
   var id = event.target.id;

   if(id){
      let item = document.getElementById(this.id);
       if(item.classList.contains("chosen")){
          item.classList.remove("chosen");
        }else{             
          item.classList.add("chosen");

       }
 //... the rest of your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, you could pass the id parameter to the chosen function, this way you would have the correct element.

This way:

**Before**

```
document.getElementById(names[i]).addEventListener("click",chosen)
.
.
.
function chosen() { 
        let item = document.getElementById(this.id);
        if(item.classList.contains("chosen"))
           item.classList.remove("chosen");
        else
           item.classList.add("chosen");
}
```

**After**

```
document.getElementById(names[i]).addEventListener("click",chosen(names[i])
.
.
.
function chosen(chosenId) { 
    const item = document.getElementById(chosenId);
    item.classList.toggle("chosen")
}
```

And try to always use **const** variables in scenarios like that, this gives more predictability to your code

Comment: Perfect Yoshi, I will refactor